# Tools to find miRNA ID

Tags: bioinformatics

How can I get accession numbers of bread wheat miRNAs by their sequences? What are the tools or website that can be used?

Comment: Somewhat out of character, I have given a (short) answer to your (even shorter) question, but you really should read the [help on asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to do some research before posting and show in your question what attempts you have made to help yourself. I do not work on wheat (or any plants, for that matter) but I know how to use the Google search engine. Did you search for "microRNAs and Triticum aestivum"? There are quite a few papers that come up that presumably could provide leads.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have a sequence, run a [nucleotide BLAST search at NCBI](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch), specifying *Triticum aestivum* (taxid:4565) as the organism.
2. The [miRBase page for *Triticum aestivum*](http://www.mirbase.org/cgi-bin/mirna_summary.pl?org=tae) has details of wheat microRNAs, and a [page](http://www.mirbase.org/search.shtml) where you can do a sequence search with either BLAST or SSEARCH (as @WYSIWYG kindly pointed out).
3. Perhaps the [*Triticum aestivum* page](http://www.plantgdb.org/TaGDB/) at PlantGDB may help.

Comment: Reg. point#2: miRBase has BLAST and SSEARCH (Smith-Waterman) for searching by sequence.

Comment: Thanks @WYSIWYG. I had thought that there must be, but presumably I didn't scroll down far enough. Have modified my answer. miRBase seems to be the place the poster should go.